# iOS Swift: WebRTC with multipeer connectivity

Tags: ios, swift3, webrtc, multipeer-connectivity, serverless

In the process of understanding webRTC workflow in iOS native applications, I am giving a try to the [application](https://github.com/Mahabali/BonjourWebrtc) which claims to be a server-less webRTC iOS application using multi peer connectivity framework. While going through its code I notice the use of a url "**stun:stun.l.google.com:19302**" in ICE server setup so how this application is server-less then? Can anybody clarifies over this? Also when I run the application over two iOS devices connected to same WiFi network then I am not able to see the remote video screen and instead a black screen appears for the remote video. The local stream displays correctly. One of the iOS device is ipad (iOS 10.3.1) and another one is an iPod (iOS 9.3.5). Is use of multi peer connectivity framework with WebRTC a good approach? Any inputs will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your all clients are behind same network, you don't have to use STUN server but in real world you will probably need to use STUN or TURN server.

Further info about ICE mechanism in WebRTC can be found [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/)

Comment: But the problem is that, I am unable to get remote output when the application is run on iOS devices without any change

Answer (score 0):

In general, WebRTC doesn't claim to be serverless. At a very minimum, you need a server for signaling so that the peers can discover each other and exchange messages needed to establish a peer-to-peer connection.

You also need STUN and TURN servers for the peers to learn what IP addresses they can be reached at, and to relay media in case a peer-to-peer connection cannot be established, respectively.

The `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` you mention is a free public STUN server hosted by Google.

Answer (score 0):

**`WebRTC`** doesn't claim to be no server. From my point You need a server for signals and for sending/receiving `ice candidates and sdps` by host/guest.
Mainly you get `one/multiple ice candidates from other side` to set into your **`peerconnection`** and one of the ice candidates matched and makes connection.